# How to add write protection to a USB drive in Ubuntu or Mint?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, usb-drive

I have an NTFS USB hard drive containing data that I'd like to protect. What's the best way to achieve this in Ubuntu or Mint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- you mean to make the *whole* USB stick read-only and not just a few particular files, and;
- The USB drive device is `/dev/sde`

#### Using `mount`

This easiest, and possibly safest, option would be to `mount` the USB drive as *read only*, using the `ro` option:

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sde /mnt
```

If the USB drive has already been automatically mounted - as read-write (`rw`) - you can just remount it as read-only:

```
sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda /mnt
```

#### Using `hdparm`

Or, if you like living dangerously, you could use `hdparm` to make the already mounted USB drive read-only

```
sudo hdparm -r1 /dev/sde
```

To make it read-write

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sde
```

To check the read/write status

```
sudo hdparm -r /dev/sde
```

Note that, as pointed out in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694487/how-to-add-write-protection-to-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-or-mint/694522#comment1313135_694522), using `hdparm` might have undesired effects: The `hdparm` setting might prevent `mount` from safely unmounting the filesystem. That would leave the filesystem flagged as mounted when in fact it's not, meaning that a filesystem check will need to be performed (or the journalled equivalent) on next mount.

Thus it would be wise to reset the mode to read-write *prior to unmounting*:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sde
```

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1600394/399707) to [Why do I need to "hdparm -r" in order to mount a Sony camcorder read/write and why is it dangerous?](https://Why%20do%20I%20need%20to%20%22hdparm%20-r%22%20in%20order%20to%20mount%20a%20Sony%20camcorder%20read/write%20and%20why%20is%20it%20dangerous?):

> the `-r` flag has been marked as dangerous between `hdparm` versions 2.3 and 2.9 (years '95-'96 - ancient!) with no elaboration, but the actual operation performed is the same to this day.
>
> ...
>
> Do note that until recently, there was a pretty nasty bug in the scsi driver (so, most standard hard drives) where the read-only flag wouldn't stick:
>
> - https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198689
> - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1548938
>
> It was fixed, but the fix has caused a new bug that forced some devices to stay read-only
>
> - https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201221
> - https://www.spinics.net/lists/stable/msg283998.html
>
> Check if your kernel has been patched against these issues.